# Copy non-na rows to fill non-na columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, na

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101],
                   'sourcename':['test1','test2','test3','test4'],
                            'Test':[np.nan,np.nan,'B5','B6']})
```

What I would like to do is copy `non-na` rows from `Test` column and paste it in corresponding row under `sourcename` column

When I tried the below, it makes the other rows of `sourcename` column as `NA`

```
df['sourcename'] = df.loc[df['Test'].notna()]['Test']
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Both the solutions are really good and am really thankful to Jezrael and Shubham. However, I can mark only one solution as answer. So, without getting into intricate details of the code, I will mark Jezrael code as answer for the multiple solutions suggested. Again, I really appreciate both of your help. Unless if Shubham and Jezrael prefer the other solution is better, I can mark that as solution.

Comment: I don't get into intricate details of the code like speed, performance etc because I don't have knowledge about that. Thanks for your help once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['sourcename'] = df['Test'].fillna(df['sourcename'])
```

Solution with check non missing values:

You are close, assign to rows filtered by mask:

```
df.loc[df['Test'].notna(), 'sourcename'] = df['Test']
```

Or:

```
df['sourcename'] = np.where(df['Test'].notna(), df['Test'], df['sourcename'])
```

Answer (score 5):

#### [`Series.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html)

We can `update` the values in `sourcename` column with the `non NaN` values from `Test` column

```
df['sourcename'].update(df['Test'])
```

---

```
>>> df

   person_id sourcename Test
0        101      test1  NaN
1        101      test2  NaN
2        101         B5   B5
3        101         B6   B6
```